# Why is the SQL compiler treating these two stored procedure calls differently?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have these two stored procedures, with the exact same `SELECT` query.
The only difference between the two procedures is that the `DATETIME` parameter `@Date` is passed in as a parameter to `Test1`, but is declared withing the procedure in `Test2`:

```
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test1
        @Date DATETIME NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.tbl_TransactionSet ts
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SWIFTTransaction s ON ts.TransactionSetId = s.TransactionSetId
        WHERE s.SWIFTTransactionDirection = 'O'
            AND s.SWIFTTransactionStatus = 'P'
            AND s.SWIFTTransactionCompleted >= @Date
        SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
    END
    GO
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Test2 
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '20 May 20'
    
        SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.tbl_TransactionSet ts
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_SWIFTTransaction s ON ts.TransactionSetId = s.TransactionSetId
        WHERE s.SWIFTTransactionDirection = 'O'
            AND s.SWIFTTransactionStatus = 'P'
            AND s.SWIFTTransactionCompleted >= @Date    
        SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
    END
    GO
    
    exec VegaBanking.dbo.Test1 @Date = '20 May 20'
    exec VegaBanking.dbo.Test2
```

`Test1` executes in 0 ms:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

`Test2` executes in 959 ms:

```
  SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 859 ms,  elapsed time = 959 ms.
```

I'm running SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU20).

The execution plan for `Test1` is (Index seeks used):

[image: Test1 execution plan]

The execution plan for `Test2` is (Index scan and sort):

[image: Test 2 execution plan]

The warning on the `SELECT` is an excessive memory grant:

[image: warning]

Can someone please help to explain why the compiler is creating a different plan for each scenario, are why the performance difference is so large?

Comment: Some variant of parameter sniffing, combined with stale table/index statistics or just incorrect query optimization by server. Usually effect is reversed - using procedure parameters directly in query gives worse performance.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a better way to include an execution plan in your question. It would also help if you added DDL for the tables and indexes to your question. Aside: [SQL Server commands to clear caches before running a performance comparison](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10818/sql-server-commands-to-clear-caches-before-running-a-performance-comparison).

Comment: I used `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear the plan cache before executing the procedures. Also rebuilt the statistics and indexes which made no difference

Comment: Out of interest, does it make any difference if the Test1 version doesn't allow the parameter to be optional?

Comment: No difference Dazz